# Value of old shares

Tags: stocks

I recently discovered I still have stock certificates from Media General from back in the 80's. The company has been sold at least twice since then. Are my shares worth anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact the Investor Relations department of the company that most recently bought them. They should be able to tell you what your options are.

Comment: Which, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_General), is Nexstar Broadcasting Group.