# Emc2 lost shares

Tags: employee-stock-options

20 years ago I worked for IT company called EMC2, today is part of Dell Technology. I received shares from EMC but forgot. Also forgot account number at Morgan Stanley.

How can I find out what I still own, if anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value of old shares](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115633/value-of-old-shares)

Comment: You'll need to reach out to Morgan Stanley.

Answer (score 3):

You could reach out to Morgan Stanley.  They should be able to help you access the account if they still have it.  They may require you to complete some paperwork to confirm your identity though.

Assuming you have moved over the past 20 years, though, I would wager that the account was considered abandoned long ago when mail came back as undeliverable and the custodian no longer had a way to reach you.  If so, the account would have been [escheated to the state](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/glossary/escheatment-financial-institutions#:%7E:text=Before%20an%20account%20is%20considered,a%20process%20called%20%22escheatment.%22).  You can contact the unclaimed property department in whatever state you were a resident of when Morgan Stanley could last contact you.  Or you can [search across states](https://missingmoney.com/).  If your account was escheated, you'll need to fill out some paperwork to claim the money.